# How to use multiprocessing module for updating each element of multi dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I want to apply multiprocessing module to speed up updating numpy array's elements.

Here's a WIP code...

```
counter = Value(c_int)  # defaults to 0
# counter_lock = Lock()
def increment():
    with counter.get_lock():
        counter.value += 1
    print(f'\r{counter.value}/{total} has been completed.', end='')

total = len(data_paths)

# Assign number to the data
data_w_num=list(enumerate(data_paths))

def prepare_data(data_w_num):
    i, imgs = data_w_num

    try:
        with data.get_lock():
            data[i] = np.array([preprocess(read_img(imgs[m]), input_shape[1:]) for m in ['t1', 't2', 't1ce', 'flair']], dtype=np.float32)
        with data.get_lock():
            labels[i] = preprocess_label(read_img(imgs['seg']), input_shape[1:])[None, ...] 

        # Print the progress bar
        increment()

    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Something went wrong with {imgs["t1"]}, skipping...\n Exception:\n{str(e)}')
        return


with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
    print('total: ' + f'{total}')
    r = p.map_async(prepare_data, data_w_num)
    print("Processing...")
    r.wait()
    print('\nAll processes were done.')
```

data_paths variable looks like:

[image]

---

But it doesn't work. 
The error message was "only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars."
And I'm not sure how to apply multiprocessing.

It would be happy if you help me to solve this.

---

Comment: So what's wrong?  You don't understand the error, or you don't know where it is happening?  Didn't your error give more information? (or is that top secret?).

Comment: The above code doesn't work. And i'm not sure that the above code is enough to achieve the goal described in title.